# C/C++ code that damages call stack

Tags: c++, callstack

Is it possible an usual code to damage call stack in c/c++?
I don't mean a kind of hack or something, just an oversight mistake or something, but not random, such that damages it every time.
Someone told me that an ex colleague managed but I don't think it is possible.
Does someone have such an experience?

Comment: It's very easy to damage call stack in C/C++. That's the reason many people hate them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, easy. One of the very common issues, in fact. Consider this:

```
void foo()
{
    int i;
    int *p = &i;
    p -= 5; // now point somewhere god knows where, generally undefined behavior
    *p = 0; // boom, on different compilers will end up with various bad things,
       // including potentially trashing the call stack
}
```

Many cases of an out-of-boundaries access of a local array/buffer end up with trashed stacks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. On many platforms, local variables are stored along with the call stack; in that case, writing outside a local array is a very easy way to corrupt it:

```
void evil() {
    int array[1];
    std::fill(array, array+1000000, 0);
    return; // BOOM!
}
```

More subtly, returning a reference to a local variable could corrupt the stack of a function that's called later on:

```
int & evil() {
    int x;
    return x;
}
void good(int & x) {
    x = 0;
    return; // BOOM!
}
void innocent() {
    good(evil());
}
```

Note that neither of these (and indeed anything else that could corrupt the stack) are legal; but the compiler doesn't have to diagnose them. Luckily, most compilers will spot these errors, as long as you enable the appropriate warnings.

Comment: And a c variant my be as linker finds double evil(double a); ...

file1.h

`double evil(double a);`

file1.c

    #include "file1.h"
    double evil(double a){return a*5;}`

main.c

    #include <stdio.h>
`double evil(void);//declaration only`

    int main(void)
    {
         printf("The result is %f, \n", evil());//BOOM
         return 0;
    }